# Creating a Boxplot between two filtered datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to create a boxplot that is comparing the revenue of Midwest states and National Income. I'm not very sure how to do it. So far, the data has already been filtered, but I'm unsure how to create the boxplot with GGplot as the data has been split into two data sets.

```
#Opening the csv file and naming it as "zoo." 
museums <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Elysa Ng\\Downloads\\archive\\museums.csv")
```

```
#Loading the libraries.
library(tidyverse)library(ggResidpanel)library(emmeans)library(car)library(dplyr)library(ggpubr)library(rstatix)
```

```
#Glimpsing the data.
glimpse(museums)

#NA omit from the income column
income <- museums %>% 
  drop_na(Income)

#plot income data distribution 
income %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Income))+
  geom_histogram()
```

Here is the filtered data for Midwest states. Now is there a way to combien the data that is all summarized here into a ggplot with the boxplot depiciting the midwest vs the national data?

```
#filter out just the organizations in the Midwest 
midwest <- income %>%filter(State..Administrative.Location. %in% c("IN", "IL", "MI", "OH", "MN", "WI", "IA", "MO"))

#looks at how many incomes from the new filtered data are 0 sum(midwest$Income=="0")

#filter out incomes equal to 0 midwest.filtered <- subset(midwest, as.numeric(Income)!=0)

#look at the summary data for non-zero incomes of all Midwest organizations 
summarize(midwest.filtered, mean=mean(Income), sd=sd(Income), median=median(Income))

#filter out incomes greater than twice the median 
midwest.filtered <- subset(midwest.filtered, as.numeric(Income) <= 337132)

#summary data for filtered zoo income nationally 
summarize(midwest.filtered, mean=mean(Income), sd=sd(Income), median=median(Income))
```

Comment: OP, the general idea would be to *not* separate or "pre-filter" the data in most cases.  You can map each dataset to a particular column in the dataset, then use that as your x axis for the box plot.  As it stands, I cannot reproduce anything in your question - can you please post a representative example?